# Efficiently storing game states history for physics?

Tags: c++, box2d, networking

I would like to store the history of a box2d simulation. Currently I can't find any built-in mechanism for that.

I need to store the states of all non static objects in the last second, mainly for network latency correction.

I think I will use a multi dimensional array for all the rigid bodies positions and forces.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as my personal experience spans, I think you are really better off saving crucial data on data structures or arrays/matrices.

I suggest you don't store all data eagerly, though. You should only store data of objects that moved or had some change to it's resulting force on given frame. This will save you from storing data of objects that are standing still and not participating in any active collisions.

If you are in a scenario with a low density of objects movements and/or collisions over time, you can even do crazy things such as Braid's time rewinding thing, since storing past states (or past state changes) wouldn't be too costly.

Comment: From memory Braid uses some system based on the command pattern. I need to access immediately the state at time T-x. Do some processing and send the updates to all players. I'd like to allocate the memory once and simply run it like that. But I might be completely wrong when it comes to my approach.

Comment: If the number of entities is low and doesn't change often, then you might be able to use your "allocate memory once" approach without blowing up your memory budget.